# mvc 4 desktop and mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mobile, web-applications

I would like to use ASP.NET MVC 4 to build a web site that will target both desktop and mobile users (will leave tablets to one side for this discussion)

There appears to be a number of options available to me and I would like to obtain some feedback.

The first option involves using the same web site for both desktop and mobile users.  Each page request would go to the respective controller and would render a view dependent on the form factor (and maybe even dependent on the device type, e.g. Windows Phone, IPhone, etc).  Responsive design would be used top ensure that the UI was suitably tailored to the expected user experience (portrait, landscape).  This option has the following benefits (as I see it):

- No duplication of controller logic
- Single site to maintain
- no redirect for the user to a different site
- no duplication of pages to inform the search crawler about

The second option involves having a separate site for mobile which only provides views and controller action methods for mobile.  This would also have the ability to provide device specific views (using display modes) and responsive design for orientation.  This option has the following benefits:

- Full controll over the mobile experience in terms of what pages are available (I know that I could conditional render action links but with this option, if functionality is not permitted on the device, a page doesnt exist in the site!
- Separate release cycles for mobile.
- But the biggest draw-back is the fact that controller logic will almost certainly be duplicated between the desktop site and the mobile site which feels like it will really hurt in the future.

It feels like the purist MVC should have the controller which should obtain the data and then provide a view which allows the data to be surfaced on the most appropriate page.  This feels like option 1.

I guess it comes down to should we have a device specific site (http://m.) or do we design a site that can be viewed from an array of devices?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Quite honesly I have seen both ways done and the first method described really is the best way of going about it. However the caution I would give you is that be sure to make the mobile experience the best it can be. I know that a lot of companies do not focus on perfecting their mobile (including my experience) and that can lose you customer. However duplication of controller logic is horrible. An even better way of doing it that was not described though would have 1 controller set but have that controller set call an set of code that acts somewhat like an api, that way if you ever need to move to option 2 you are not dupulicating code and life gets easier in moving. Anyways if you have any further questions I would be happy to chat, I am a professional mobile developer and know every aspect of the web interactions between iPhone Android, WP7, etc.